# PHP - Notice: Undefined index: submenu

Tags: php

I'm trying to create an menu with `submenus`.

I created two tables on my database, here the data:

Menu table -

```
menu_id
front
back
url 
menu_friendlyname   
name
modules active
```

Submenu table -

```
submenu_id
menu_id url
submenu_name    
modules
```

I'm doing a specie of MVC, but with my own rules, here the model:

I'm calling two tables here

```
    $query = ("SELECT DISTINCT name, menu_id
      FROM menu
      INNER JOIN submenu USING(menu_id)");

    $array = db_array($query, 'a+');
    if (!empty($array)) {
        printMenu($array);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And I'm calling the view here, as you can see, I'm trying to show the `submenus`

```
function  printMenu($array){


echo '<pre>';
var_dump($array);
echo '</pre>';
foreach($array as $key => $values){

echo '<ul>';

echo '<li>';
echo $values['name'];
echo '</li>';


echo '<li>';

foreach($values['submenu'] as $k => $v){
echo '<span>';
echo $v['submenu'];
echo '</span>';

}

echo '</li></ul>';

}
}
```

And is giving me this **error**:

```
Notice: Undefined index: submenu
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

I did a var_dump too

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "admin"
    ["menu_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "user"
    ["menu_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["

name"]=>
        string(22) "permissions_management"
        ["menu_id"]=>
        string(1) "3"
      }
      [3]=>
      array

(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "job_offers"
    ["menu_id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "applications"
    ["menu_id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
  }
}
```

Maybe the error is from the array

Comment: Which line number that, Undefined index error showing?

Comment: its 'Undefined index' because in our sql you only select name and menu_id.

Comment: There is not submenu in your array, so you try to access submenu but that does not exists. You could check if submenu exists byt using `isset()`

Comment: at line 26: code: foreach($values['submenu'] as $k => $v){

Comment: A "notice" is _not_ an "error".

Comment: both errors and warnings are in line 26

Comment: @arkascha This notice is being caused by a logic error in his program.

Comment: There's no `submenu` column in either of your tables, and your query isn't returning anything aliased to `submenu`. And even if it did, it wouldn't be an array -- table columns are always scalar values.

Comment: @Bamar I am well aware why that notice is raised. Still it is not an error. And it is important to see the difference. Thus my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be:

```
SELECT menu_id, name, submenu_name
FROM menu
INNER JOIN submenu USING (menu_id)
ORDER BY menu_id, submenu_id
```

Then the function to print the menus should be:

```
function  printMenu($array){
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($array);
    echo '</pre>';

    $last_menu = null;
    foreach($array as $values){
        if ($values['menu_id'] !== $last_menu) {
            if ($last_menu !== null) {
                echo '</ul>';
            }
            echo '<ul>';
            echo '<li>';
            echo $values['name'];
            echo '</li>';
            $last_menu = $values['menu_id'];
        }
        echo '<li>';
        echo '<span>';
        echo $v['submenu_name'];
        echo '</span>';
    }
    if ($last_menu !== null) {
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to prevent the $last_menu?

Comment: You could write another function that loops through `$array` and combines all the elements with the same `menu_id` into a single element, with the submenus as a nested array. But it will be similar to this function, except instead of printing things it will be merging array elements.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a "submenu" key in your values sub-array. The only keys you have there are name and menu_id. That's why you are getting an undefined index error.

Answer (score 0):

Before your iteration, also check if `$values['submenu']` presents or not.

```
if(isset($values['submenu']) && $values['submenu'] != '') {    
    foreach($values['submenu'] as $k => $v){
      echo '<span>';
      echo $v['submenu'];
      echo '</span>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Since there's no `submenu` in his query, this will always fail, so why even bother?

Comment: I dont have errors anymore, but the problem is from the query, i dont know to structure the query