# PHP - How can i use UNION all on those two queries

Tags: php, sql

I want to merge those queries in one, using union all, how can i do that?

```
$query = ("SELECT menu_id, menu_friendlyName
        FROM menu
        WHERE back = 1 AND active = 1")


$query = ("SELECT menu_id, submenu_id, submenu_name, url
        FROM submenu
        WHERE active = 1");
```

Comment: What do you want the result to look like?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use UNION? I think, you need JOIN or LEFT JOIN rather. What you would like to do? Select all menu entries with corresponding submenu entries?

Comment: Maybe you want something like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984077/php-notice-undefined-index-submenu/22984512#22984512

Comment: In fact, it looks like you're working on the same menu system as him. Your tables seem the same.

Answer (score 0):

For example this way:

```
$query =
  "select * from (
   SELECT
      menu_id,
      menu_friendlyName,
      NULL as submenu_id,
      NULL as url,
   FROM menu
   WHERE back = 1 AND active = 1
    union all 
   SELECT
      menu_id,
      NULL as menu_friendlyName,
      submenu_id,
      submenu_name,
      url,
   FROM submenu
   WHERE active = 1) x"
);
```

Otherwise as others mentioned the union doesn't really look a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select menu entries with corresponding submenu entries you have to use **JOIN** instead. I would use **LEFT JOIN** for this:

```sql
SELECT m.menu_id, m.menu_friendlyName, s.submenu_id, s.submenu_name, s.url
FROM menu AS m
LEFT JOIN submenu AS s
    ON s.menu_id = m.menu_id
WHERE
    m.back = 1
    AND m.active = 1
    AND s.active = 1
```

If you use **JOIN**, the query returns menu entries, which have at least one submenu entry. If you use **LEFT JOIN**, it returns also menu entries without any submenu entry.